# Python transformers library not giving an answer

Tags: python, transformer-model

so i made some code which just asks this:
"What is the capital of France?"
but instead it responds with this:
"what is the capital of france"

here is the code i tried:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch

# Load the pre-trained model and tokenizer
model_name = "bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad"  
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Define the question
question = "What is the capital of France?"

# Tokenize the input
inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(question, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")

# Perform inference
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    start_scores = outputs.start_logits
    end_scores = outputs.end_logits
    all_tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(inputs["input_ids"].squeeze())
    answer_start = torch.argmax(start_scores)
    answer_end = torch.argmax(end_scores)
    answer = " ".join(all_tokens[answer_start:answer_end + 1])

# Print the answer
print(f"{answer}")
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this model can only answer in terms of a token or tokens that you gave it. So if you gave it a question like `question = "[CLS] What is the capital of France? [SEP] London is the capital of england. Paris is the capital of France. [SEP]"`, attaching a document with context inside the [SEP] tags, then it can answer. But if you don't, then it can't reply with anything except the words in the question.